# Consecutive negative numbers in a data frame

Tags: python, function, dataframe

This is the sample of my dataset:

```
                        fvc  pef  fev1  fev1_fvc  fev6  fev25_75  fvc_changes
Date        Time                                        
2017-03-14  19:27:14    2.7  3.7  1.7   0.63      1.8   0.9         0.00
2017-03-15  11:35:21    3.1  2.8  2.0   0.65      2.2   1.2        14.81
2017-03-16  15:37:02    2.8  2.6  1.8   0.62      1.9   1.0         3.70
2017-03-17  17:11:16    2.8  3.1  1.9   0.66      2.0   1.2         3.70
2017-03-18  20:29:35    2.9  3.4  1.8   0.64      2.0   1.0         7.41
2017-03-19  21:53:09    2.2  4.1  1.5   0.65      2.2   0.8       -18.52
            21:54:23    2.4  4.1  1.7   0.71      1.8   1.2       -11.11
2017-03-20  14:36:24    2.3  4.1  1.6   0.69      1.7   1.0       -14.81
2017-03-21  22:36:43    2.1  4.0  1.4   0.63      1.4   0.8       -22.22
```

This is the function I've written to get to this stage.

```
def fvc_changes(df, fvc_base=2.7):
    # for loop to calculate fvc changes from baseline
    for fvc in df:
        changes = ((df['fvc'] - fvc_base) / fvc_base) * 100
        changes = round(changes, 2)

    # add result into new column: fvc_changes
    df['fvc_changes'] = changes
    return
```

I would like to extend this function in such a way that:

1. it will go through fvc_changes column (start to end) and check if it has a value less than -10
2. if it encounters a third negative value (of less than -10) CONSECUTIVELY, then it will print "EXACERBATION" in a new column attached to the same data frame
3. the function will ONLY evaluate the final value of fvc_changes for any given date i.e. if one date has two fvc_changes, it will only evaluate the second value of fvc_changes

The final data frame should look like this:

```
                        fvc  pef  fev1  fev1_fvc  fev6  fev25_75  fvc_changes  exacerbation
Date        Time                                        
2017-03-14  19:27:14    2.7  3.7  1.7   0.63      1.8   0.9         0.00 
2017-03-15  11:35:21    3.1  2.8  2.0   0.65      2.2   1.2        14.81
2017-03-16  15:37:02    2.8  2.6  1.8   0.62      1.9   1.0        -3.70
2017-03-17  17:11:16    2.8  3.1  1.9   0.66      2.0   1.2         3.70
2017-03-18  20:29:35    2.9  3.4  1.8   0.64      2.0   1.0         7.41
2017-03-19  21:53:09    2.2  4.1  1.5   0.65      2.2   0.8       -18.52
            21:54:23    2.4  4.1  1.7   0.71      1.8   1.2       -11.11
2017-03-20  14:36:24    2.3  4.1  1.6   0.69      1.7   1.0       -14.81
2017-03-21  22:36:43    2.1  4.0  1.4   0.63      1.4   0.8       -22.22        EXACERBATION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this in a few steps, though there might be a smarter way

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['exacerbation'] = df.groupby(level=0).fvc_changes.transform(lambda x: x.tail(1) <-10)
df['exacerbation'] = (df.groupby(df.exacerbation.astype('int').diff().abs().cumsum()).exacerbation
                        .apply(lambda x: x.cumsum() > 3))
df['exacerbation'] = df['exacerbation'].replace(np.NaN, False)

df['exacerbation'] = np.where(df.exacerbation, 'EXACERBATION', '')
```

---

- The first line creates the `exacerbation` column and indicates whether the last value for that day is `< 10`
- The second line determines whether there is a streak of more than 3 days where the last value is `< -10`. Exacerbation now contains `True` everywhere it should be assigned `'EXACERBATON'`.
- The third line replaces `NaN` with `False` so it isn't interpreted as `True` by `np.where`
- The fourth line fills in the values you want, based on the above logic.

---

I added a few rows for testing to your `df`. Here's the output

```
                     fvc_changes  exacerbation
Date       Time                               
2017-03-14 19:27:14         0.00              
2017-03-15 11:35:21        14.81              
2017-03-16 15:37:02         3.70              
2017-03-17 17:11:16         3.70              
2017-03-18 20:29:35         7.41              
2017-03-19 21:53:09       -18.52              
           21:54:23       -11.11              
2017-03-20 14:36:24       -14.81              
2017-03-21 22:36:43       -22.22  EXACERBATION
2017-03-24 17:11:16         3.70              
2017-03-25 20:29:35         7.41              
2017-03-26 21:53:09       -18.52              
2017-03-27 21:54:23       -11.11              
2017-03-28 14:36:24       -14.81              
2017-03-29 22:36:43       -22.22  EXACERBATION
```

---

Edit: I think the above logic may not be entirely correct with what you want. Here's a slightly different approach which should work. The above considers multiple values on the same 'day' as a streak. This method will only count the last value for a day in the streak. You can see in the output that though the last 4 rows have negative values, they only span 2 days so it's not counted.

```
import pandas as pd
df['exacerbation'] = df.groupby(level=0).fvc_changes.transform(lambda x: x.tail(1) < -10 )
df2 = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates('Date', keep='last')
df2['exacerbation'] = (df2.groupby(df2.exacerbation.astype('int').diff().abs().cumsum()).exacerbation
                          .apply(lambda x: x.cumsum() >= 3))

df2['exacerbation'] = df2['exacerbation'].replace(np.NaN, False)
df = df.merge(df2[['Date', 'Time', 'exacerbation']], left_index=True, right_on=['Date', 'Time'], how='left',
              suffixes=['_', '']).drop(columns='exacerbation_').set_index(['Date', 'Time']).fillna(method='bfill')

df['exacerbation'] = np.where(df.exacerbation, 'EXACERBATION', '')
```

Outputs:

```
                     fvc_changes  exacerbation
Date       Time                               
2017-03-14 19:27:14         0.00              
2017-03-15 11:35:21        14.81              
2017-03-16 15:37:02         3.70              
2017-03-17 17:11:16         3.70              
2017-03-18 20:29:35         7.41              
2017-03-19 20:53:09       -12.52              
           21:53:09       -18.52              
           21:54:23       -11.11              
2017-03-20 14:36:24       -14.81              
2017-03-21 22:36:43       -22.22  EXACERBATION
2017-03-24 17:11:16         3.70              
2017-03-25 20:29:35         7.41              
2017-03-26 21:53:09       -18.52              
2017-03-27 21:54:23       -11.11              
2017-03-28 14:36:24       -14.81  EXACERBATION
2017-03-29 22:36:43       -22.22  EXACERBATION
2017-03-30 22:36:43        22.22              
2017-04-02 20:53:09       -12.52              
           21:53:09       -18.52              
           21:54:23       -11.11              
2017-04-03 14:36:24       -14.81
```

Comment: nice use of lambda :)

Comment: @Mahf_i, actually I think there may be a small mistake in the logic. I'll try to see if I can fix it.